# Is it possible to execute the same query i'm using inside an IF EXISTS statement without repeating it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This really silly question just popped out of my mind out of curiosity; i'm still learning how to write better code in SQL and i just found myself in the situation where i have to **check if the result of a query exists** and then, if that was true, **execute the same exact query to create a new table.**
The code is working and considering i'm not dealing with large amounts of data i have no problems of computation times but...it's simply *ugly* and **i would like to make it more...*appealing?***

This is the code i'm refering to:

```
[...]

IF EXISTS  (SELECT  *value*, COUNT(*) AS Repetitions       
           FROM  *table*         
           GROUP BY *value*
           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

   SELECT *value*, COUNT(*) AS Repetitions
   INTO dbo.*newtable*
   FROM  *table*         
   GROUP BY *data*
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

ELSE

[...]
```

Comment: Do you really need to checl if it exists before executing it ? can't you just deal with NULL any other way ?

Comment: Do the `SELECT ... INTO` unconditionally, then drop the table if it's empty (assuming that's even necessary). Unless you're doing this several times per second or you have DDL triggers that do expensive things, you don't need to go out of your way to avoid creation of an empty table -- the query is the expensive part. (And even if you do, you could use a table variable or temp table as an intermediate.)

Comment: If you execute without checking it, it will insert nothing. So everthing is OK, isn't it?

Comment: Okay yeah i'm just stupid, i didn't even thought at the fact that I could just skip the checking phase. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing an `exists` first is unecessary.

Simply do

```
select <columns> into NewTable
From Table
where criteria;

if @@rowcount=0 
begin
  drop table NewTable;
end
else
begin
  /* Actions if table created */
end
```